# Designing an object rendering system

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, interface

I wrote some code which consists of a set of objects which implement a simple interface. These objects are just plain DTO's. They need to rendered. Each one requires it's own renderer. I initially think OK so there will be a renderer interface which has one method `render` and it will accept an result `ResultInterface`. Each result item has different pieces of extra data which need to be rendered.

So what actually happens is that each renderer then checks it receives the correct type. So although it seems it accepts anything implementing `ResultInterface` it actually doesn't. Then I think, well why do I even bother type hinting on `ResultInterface`.

Here are a few examples to illustrate:

```
<?php

Interface RendererInterface
{
    public function render(ResultInterface $result);
}


class ExceptionFailureRenderer implements RendererInterface
{
    public function render(ResultInterface $result)
    {
        if (!$result instanceof ExceptionFailure) {

            throw new InvalidArgumentException;
        }
    }
}

class SomeOtherFailureRenderer implements RendererInterface
{
    public function render(ResultInterface $result)
    {
        if (!$result instanceof SomeOtherFailure) {

            throw new InvalidArgumentException;
        }
    }
}

Interface ResultInterface
{
    public function getName();
}

class ExceptionFailure implements ResultInterface
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Exception Failure';
    }

    public function getException()
    {
        return $this->exception;
    }
}

class SomeOtherFailure implements ResultInterface
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Some Other Failure';
    }

    public function getSomeOtherPieceOfData()
    {
        return $this->importantData;
    }
}

$renderers = [
    ExceptionFailure::class => new ExceptionFailureRenderer,
    SomeOtherFailure::class => new SomeOtherFailureRenderer
];

$output = '';
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $renderer = $renderers[get_class($result)];
    $output  .= $renderers->render($result);
}
```

**Question**

How could this be designed better to avoid calling concrete methods when `Renderer` only expects `ResultInterface` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right that there is a design flaw here.
Having an object that implements an interface only to throw exceptions when fulfilling the implied contract is an obvious code smell.

There are a number of ways to refactor this, here is how i would do it.

Looking at the concrete `RendererInterface` implementations, its obvious they are tied to a concrete `ResultInterface` so should explicitly declare that dependency. *(WTF?? see note at bottom)*

As immutable objects are generally easier to work with, and there doesnt appear to be a decent reason to reuse a `RendererInterface` implementation (it doesnt appear to be expensive to instantiate, or have any side effects in doing so) i decided to alter `RendererInterface` by making the `render` method parameterless, and have the concrete result object injected into the constructor:

```
Interface RendererInterface
{
    public function render();
}


class ExceptionFailureRenderer implements RendererInterface
{
    private $result;
    public function __construct(ExceptionFailure $result)
    {
        $this->result = $result;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        echo '<p>'.$this->result->getException().'</p>';
    }
}

class SomeOtherFailureRenderer implements RendererInterface
{
    private $result;
    public function __construct(SomeOtherFailure $result)
    {
        $this->result = $result;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        echo '<p>'.$this->result->getSomeOtherPieceOfData().'</p>';
    }
}
```

Now that the concrete renderers are tied to the concrete results they require, you need a way to get the correct renderer given a concrete result.
The obvious answer is a factory:

```
interface RenderFactoryInterface
{
    /***
     * @param ResultInterface $result
     * @return RendererInterface
     */
    public function getRenderer(ResultInterface $result);
}

class RenderFactory implements RenderFactoryInterface
{

    //could be injected into constructor
    private $renderMap = [
        ExceptionFailure::class => ExceptionFailureRenderer::class,
        SomeOtherFailure::class => SomeOtherFailureRenderer::class

    ];


    public function getRenderer(ResultInterface $result)
    {
        if(!isset($this->renderMap[get_class($result)])){
            //write a more suitable exception class
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
            //or perhaps return a defaultRenderer that only works on
            //the methods defined in `ResultInterface`
        }
        return new $this->renderMap[get_class($result)]($result);
    }
}
```

Your consuming code would simply require a collection of `ResultInterface` objects and an implementation of `RenderFactoryInterface` to do its work, having no knowledge of the specific types of `ResultInterface` within the collection, nor any knowledge of how to tie a `ResultInterface` to a `RendererInterface`:

```
class Consumer
{
    private $results;
    private $renderFactory;

    /***
     * @param ResultInterface[] $results php doesnt have typed collections let
     * @param RenderFactoryInterface $renderFactory
     */
    public function __construct(array $results, RenderFactoryInterface $renderFactory)
    {
        $this->results = $results;
        $this->renderFactory = $renderFactory;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        foreach($this->results as $result){
            $this->renderFactory->getRenderer($result)->render();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the above is using php 5, which does not have a method to declare return types, php 7 would allow you to be more specific that the `getRenderer` method should return an implementation of `RendererInterface`.
Also, the consumer code can only typehint an array, hopefully typed collections will arrive sometime soon.

Also, as a pre-emptive to `"Typehint a concrete class?? WTF are you thinking"` this example is intended to be as brief as possible. You could of course create an `ExceptionFailureInterface`, and an `SomeOtherFailureInterface`, typehint those, and have the concrete `ResultInterface` classes implement the correct one (along with `ResultInterface`)if you think the added flexability is worth the added complexity.
My point with this answer is that the concrete `RendererInterface` classes require a more specific contract than `ResultInterface` can offer, be that a concrete class (as shown) or more specific interface

Comment: Thankyou, this makes more sense. Few things: doesn't this make the `__construct` part of the `RendererInterface` contract now? What if the renderers have more and different dependencies? Lastly, the renderers now contain seemingly unnecessary state. I agree that specific interfaces for each result seems overkill, as I have lots of different results in the system.

Comment: hello @AydinHassan To answer your questions in reverse order, there is nothing above the explicitly adds state. Take for example `ExceptionFailureRenderer` - any instance of it must contain a single instance of `ExceptionFailure`, this cannot be changed, there is no other state - the object is immutable. Of course you could change that by adding methods that alter it (such as a setter), but my code does not contain any that do.

Comment: With regards to `RendererInterface` no the constructor does not form part of the contract. The interface simply guarantees that any object that implements it contains a public, parameterless method named `render`. Any object the depends on an instance of `RendererInterface` simply expects to be given such an object, it does not know or care how it is constructed. Of course any concrete implementation of `RenderFactoryInterface` **will** need to know how to construct the various types, but thats expected.

Comment: This information needs to held somewhere, and the factory is the ideal place - its only responsibility is to create these objects. As hinted at in the example, for even further decoupling you could inject the actual mappings into the factory

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications Steve, I am going to refactor the code soon and have a go implementing your suggestions!

Comment: Glad i could help you Aydin, and problems or questions leave a comment

Comment: Hey @Steve I refactored using your suggestions here: https://github.com/php-school/php-workshop/pull/71 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using interfaces with defined functions which are not actually used by the class which implements them.

```
class ExceptionFailureRenderer (missing implements Renderer)
{
    public function render(ResultInterface $result)
    {
        if (!$result instanceof ExceptionFailure) {

            throw new InvalidArgumentException;
        }
    }
}
```

If I was to write this code I would use an abstract class prefixing the interfaces with I to IRenderer and IResultInterface (avoid confusion between the classes);

```
abstract class Renderer implements IRenderer
{ 
        public function render(IResultInterface $result)
        {
            //abstract logic here
        }    
}

class ExceptionFailureRenderer extends Renderer
{
    //overide the logic if required
}
```

Additionally I would use a RendererFactory, repository or a similar design pattern to manage which render to use. This would prevent some coupling with certain Renderer objects.

```
class RenderFactory {

     protected $instances = [];

     public function registerRenderer(IRenderer $renderer) {
          $this->instances[$renderer::class] = $renderer;
     }  

     public function doRender(ResultInterface $resultInterface) {
         //logic to retrive the renderer
     }

}

$renderFactory = new RenderFactory();
$renderFactory->registerRenderer(new ExceptionFailureRenderer());
$renderFactory->doRender($exceptionFaliureResult);
```

This of course is preferential and this is not an answer just an opinion on how I would do it. I think your answer is quite vague as there is no answer.

Comment: I already do all of what you mention, I just omitted it for clarity. The question was more about using the undefined methods. I know it is vauge, I guess the real question is about using undefined methods, I'll update the post. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood. Thanks